How to resample an ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine using bicubic method
I am trying to resample a Sentinel 2A ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine using the bicubic method. However, the resulted map is weird. I am using the folloiwng code. I apprecite if somebody help me to fix this issue:
In the following code, I define an area of interest (aoi) and a fucntion to get Sentinel 2A images for the aoi and a specific date. The function also clip and mosaic the ImageCollectoin. The bicubic method is used to resample the ImageCollection.
/**
 * Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 * @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 * @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var aoi = 
    /* color: #98ff00 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-82.14606816037433, 42.900619674967885],
          [-82.14606816037433, 42.48476153151389],
          [-81.48963505490558, 42.48476153151389],
          [-81.48963505490558, 42.900619674967885]]], null, false);
   
// Show aoi on map
Map.addLayer(aoi, {color: 'yellow'});

// Funcion to clip the sentinel bands
function clipping(im){
   return im.clip(aoi)
}

// Function to get Sentinel 2A images for an aoi and specific date
function getSentinel2WithinDateRange(start,end,aoi){
  var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                    .filterBounds(aoi)
                    .filterDate(start, end)
                    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                    .map(maskS2clouds);
                    
  return sentinel2.map(clipping).mosaic()
}

var date_start = '2024-05-29'
var date_end = '2024-06-30'

var collections = getSentinel2WithinDateRange(date_start, date_end,aoi)
print('Collection info', collections.getInfo())

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

Map.centerObject(aoi)

Map.addLayer(collections, visualization, 'RGB');

// Resample the collection using bicubic method
var resampled = collections.resample('bicubic')

print ('resample', resampled.getInfo())

var visualization = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

// Display the resampled images
Map.addLayer(resampled,visualization);

The original image:

The resampled Band 1 (In Arcgis):

The info of the resampled image:


Can you edit your question and include a link to an extract of the output image? How  does it look weird?

@mkennedy please see the image of the output

I don't think that lovely rainbow is band 1, if you produced it with this script (which visualizes 4-3-2). This kind of effect is often what you get when you visualize longitude coordinates rather than actual values. Could we see what got printed in resampled.getInfo?

First, you are probably doing a thing that doesn't need to be done.
But assuming for some reason you really need a resample, once you mosaic() the collection no longer has a projection, and resample needs one in order to be able to get neighboring pixels from which to resample.  So you need to provide a default projection for that to work. Move the mosaic() step to later and do something like this:
var proj = collections.first().select(1).projection()
// Resample the collection using bicubic method
var resampled = collections.mosaic().setDefaultProjection(proj).resample('bicubic')

But like I said, unless you're actually changing the projection, resampling doesn't do anything useful.

Thanks. It worked
